# Joomla 1.5 media manager does not change paths

Tags: php, iframe, joomla, media

I do have a working version of joomla 1.5 and uses the Media Manager.
 It works fine.
When I am trying to load the joomla administration in a n iframe when i ask from media manager's left menu to change a folder, then the folder items are displayed correctly on the right files area but the path input stays to C:\Users\akis\xampp\htdocs\joomlacom\images If your try to upload a file the file will be uploaded into the C:\Users\akis\xampp\htdocs\joomlacom\images and not the folder you have selected.

Any ideas?

Comment: What I've found so far is taht the onnloadframe function in MediaManager (at administrator/components/com_media/assets/mediamanager.js) is not called when you click on a folder (in order to change folder). By adding MediaManager.onloadfolder(); just after window.frames[target].location.href = node.data.url; at Mediamanager  initialize it solves the problem when you are running the joomla admin within an iframe (of course it calls the function twice if you work joomla aministrator as normal). It looks like the event is not caught when in iframe

Comment: Half problem fixed by adding this line 
if (window.frameElement!=null) MediaManager.onloadframe();
inside the onClick function in order to detect if you are within an iframe to manualy call the onloadframe function.
               
                    window.frames[target].location.href = node.data.url;
                    if (window.frameElement!=null) MediaManager.onloadframe();
              
The only proble now is that when you click a folder in the Files area it does changes the folder contents but it does not change the actual path (onloadframe is not called again)